# How to get the min value of a column in a SharePoint list?

Tags: database, list, sharepoint, max, min

Total newbie here. I just started to create a database (list) for a race event. The task is to have a column that lists the gap for everyone (difference between the given racer and the 1st place time). The values are stored in secs value as an integer. For example

```
Name | Time (s) |  Gap (s)
-----|----------|-----------
Dan  |   7582   |   1020     <- Second place
Greg |   6562   |      0     <- Fisrt place
Adam |   8252   |   1690     <- Third place
```

The `[Time (s)]-MIN([Time (s)]`doesn't work, as it only displays 0-s. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Regards,
Tamás

Comment: Are you talking about a SharePoint list or RDBMS table?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I'm talking about a SharePoint list. (edited it in the post also)